# Divergence theorem for cylindrical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, integration, vector-fields, volume

I have a Vector field in a cylinder where x^2+y^2=4 and goes from z=0 to z=3 and a vector field A=(4x)i-(2y^2)j+(z^2)k and I'm trying to verify the divergence theorem for the vector field i set set the volume triple integral equal to the surface double integral but cant get the correct answer as i get different values for the left hand and right hand side can I get some advice ?

for the volume integral:
-firstly I did div(A)=2+2z
-then dV = rz drdzdtheta
-volume integral = 108(pi)

for the surace integral I have:
-int(A*n ds)
-n=(cos(theta))i+(sin(theta))j+(o)k
-ds = z dz dtheta
-surface integral =12(pi)

Comment: How are we supposed to know where you've gone wrong? You should show the working atleast